# Umarshalling large unstructured REST/JSON Response

Tags: json, go

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to unmarshal a large unstructured json response into a usable object.

Here is a sample response (trimmed to show the part I'm having trouble with)

This has been *greatly* trimmed as this is a very large json response. I left the struct tags off below as well for simplicity.

```
{
    "responseStatus": "ok",
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": "ok",
        "requestId": "blah"
    },
    "responseData": {
        "records": [
            {
                "name": "blah",
                "site": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "west"
                },
                "somevar1": "someval",
                "somevar2": {
                    "x": 2,
                    "y": 1
                },
                "entries": [
                    {
                        "model": "100",
                    },
                    {
                        "model": "200",
                    }
                ]
            },
      ]
}
```

So records is a large list of "objects". I need to convert these to a type I defined. The "entries" list also needs to be converted to its object type.

```
type Record struct {
    Name         string
    Site         map[string]string
    Somevar1     string
    Somevar2     map[string]string
    Entries      []Entry
}

type Entry struct {
    Model       string

}
```

Here I can get the responseData into an object I can iterate over:

```
results := data["responseData"].(map[string]interface{})
devices := results["records"].([]interface{})

for _, device := range devices {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%T\n", device)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%+v\n", device)
}
```

Here is a sample output from 1 iteration:

```
map[string]interface {}
map[name:foo site:map[id:2 name:somewhere somevar1: blah somevar2:map[x:1 y:2] entries:[map[model:100]  map[model:200]
```

This is where I'm stuck. I need to take this line above and get convert it into my type Record while also converting the Entries to []Entry.

Comment: The structure looks fine, with the exception of the json tags. What is the problem you're seeing? If some keys are missing, they will be left empty when unmarshaled.

Comment: "Unstructured" is maybe not the right word (if it's valid JSON, it's structured), but it seems like you're talking about dynamic or unpredictable JSON. In that case, there's some key questions to ask here: 1) do you need all of the data, or just certain fields? And 2) which parts vary and how do they vary?

Comment: May or may not containing some keys is a feature of JSON; to Adrian's point, it's not unstructured. If it was unpredictable, that would prove more challenging; So is there any kind of data contract, or are you expecting to take in just random stuff and parse it?

Comment: I'm mainly needing the records object so I can iterate over it. I can unpack responseData["records"] to the point I can iterate over it but every attempt to assert that into one of my structs fails with various errors. Also I left out the struct tags just for simplicity.

Comment: What are you unmarshaling the overall document into? You've only shown type definitions for a child field of a child field. Based on your comment it seems like you're unmarshaling into a map, in which case no, you can't assert that to any struct type; it will be unmarshaled [according to the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal), i.e. using only built-in types.

Comment: Note that it's not unusual at all to define a type which only includes the fields you care about; any fields in the JSON that do not appear in the struct will just be ignored. So if the fields you need are well-defined and predictable (i.e. always have the same keys and types), there's no real trick to it.

Comment: Change `Site` and `Somevar2` to `map[string]interface{}` or to a proper struct, because their corresponding json contains ints, so when you use only `map[string]string` it will fail. Other than that your code works https://play.golang.com/p/rTgaXhXD1V6

Comment: I added my code.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Site` and `Somevar2` fields to `map[string]interface{}` or to a proper struct, because their corresponding json contains ints, so when you use only `map[string]string` it will fail.

Other than that your code works https://play.golang.com/p/rTgaXhXD1V6